# Let $V_1, V_2$ be finitely generated vector spaces. Show that $\dim(V_1 \oplus V_2) = \dim V_1 + \dim V_2$

Tags: linear-algebra

How would one show that the following property holds for all finitely generated vector spaces?

Comment: First off, to add spaces, they must be subspaces of some common space. Second, this isn't true. Consider $V_1=V_2$.

Comment: You cannot show that as it does not hold. Take for example two $2$-dimensional subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^3$. Then the sum of their dimensions will be $4$ which is impossible inside of $\mathbb{R}^3$. What you want only works for direct sums.

Comment: You probably mean the direct sum, it is written $V_1 \oplus V_2$ (latex symbol $\oplus$ is \oplus)

Comment: Thanks @OlivierRoche, that's exactly what I mean. I'm newer to this program, and I'm trying I couldn't find the code.

Comment: For future reference, there is a guide for math formatting [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 2):

by exhibiting a basis of $V_1\oplus V_2$ in terms of a basis of $V_1$ and a basis of $V_2$.

Comment: ....and the only common vector be $0$.

Comment: Thank you very much. Much clearer now.

Answer (score 2):

If $V_1,V_2$ are subspaces of a vector space $V$, then 
$$\operatorname{dim}(V_1 + V_2) = \operatorname{dim}(V_1) + \operatorname{dim}(V_2) - \operatorname{dim}(V_1 \cap V_2)$$

Now say $V_1$ and $V_2$ are vector spaces over the same field $K$, on can define a new $K$-vector space $V_1 \oplus V_2$ as follow :

- The underlying set is the cartesian product $V_1 \times V_2 = \{(u, v) \ \big| u \in V_1 \textrm{ and } v \in V_2\}$.
- The addition is defined componentwise : $(u, v) + (u',v') := (u + u', v + v')$.
- Multiplication by a scalar is also done componentwise : $k \cdot (u, v) := (k\cdot u, k\cdot v)$.

**NB :** The zero of $V_1 \oplus V_2$ is $0_{V_1 \oplus V_2} := (0_{V_1},0_{V_2})$

Now assume $V_1$ and $V_2$ are finitely generated, we will prove :
$$\operatorname{dim}(V_1 \oplus V_2) = \operatorname{dim}(V_1) + \operatorname{dim}(V_2)$$

**Proof :**
Say $\operatorname{dim}(V_1) = n$ and $\operatorname{dim}(V_1) = m$. Let $(e_1, \dots, e_n)$ and $(f_1,\dots,f_m)$ be basis of $V_1$ and $V_2$ respectively. We claim that $\mathcal{B} := \big((e_1,0), \dots, (e_n,0),\ (0, f_1), \dots (0, f_m)\big)$ is a basis of $V_1 \oplus V_2$.

- $\mathcal{B}$ is a generating family :
  Let $w \in V_1 \oplus V_2$, say $w = (u,v)$ where $u \in V_1$ and $v \in V_2$. We can write $u, v$ in their basis, say $u = \sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i e_i$ and $v = \sum_{j=1}^m \beta_j f_j$. It now appears that
  $$w = \lambda_1(e_1,0) + \dots + \lambda_n (e_n,0) + \beta_1 (0,f1) + \dots + \beta_m (0, f_m) $$
  whence the claim.
- $\mathcal{B}$ is linearly independent :
  Suppose $\lambda_1, \dots, \lambda_{n}, \beta_1, \dots, \beta_m \in K$ are such that
  $\sum_i \lambda_i (e_i,0) + \sum_j \beta_j (0, f_j) = 0_{V_1 \oplus V_2}$. 
  We need to prove that all $\lambda_i$s and all $\beta_j$s are $0$. But then we have $\sum_i \lambda_i e_i = 0$, hence $\lambda_1 = \dots = \lambda_n = 0$. Likewise, the $\beta_j$s are identically $0$, QED.